# Implementation of multiple active record associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to set up models for my Ruby on Rails app and the models are quite complicated -- I'm not sure if I'm approaching it in the right way. Reading up on the Ruby on Rails guides @ guides.rubyonrails.org gives some pretty good information about Active Record associations but it also confused me a good deal more to an extent. What I'm trying to set up is something that models a tournament but not a traditional tournament (if anyone follows the GSL, that's the tournament I'd like to try to model).

The tournament model stores the following information:

- Name
- Banner (just a url to a picture hosted online)
- Map Pool (a collection of Map objects that are in use for the tournament)
- Players (a number of players that are participating in this tournament)
- Rounds of 32 to the finals (Round of 32, 16, 8, 4, 2)

These are the models I have come up with: Tournament, Map Pool, Map, Player, Race (i.e. Protoss Terran or Zerg), Team (i.e. what team the player belongs to), Round_of_32, Round_of_16, Round_of_8, Round_of_4, Round_of_2, Group (a collection of matches per round), Match (a collection that has information per matchup between players), and a Game (which holds a map and a winner). As the app develops, I will be having more and more tournaments, each with its own set of data, even though players could be parts of multiple tournaments and maps could be part of multiple map pools for their respective tournaments, etc.

- A tournament has a map pool that includes a number of maps
- A tournament has multiple players, each of which is associated with a different race and team
- A round of 32 has eight groups, each with five matches, each with 3 games
- A round of 16 is similar to a round of 32 but it only has four groups
- A round of 8 has just 4 matches, each with 5 games
- A round of 4 has 2 matches, each with 5 games
- A round of 2 has 1 match, each with 7 games

Here is what I have so far:

```
TOURNAMENT
  :league
  :banner
  has_one :map_pool
  has_many :maps, :through => :map_pool
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  # has_many :rounds
  has_one :ro32
  has_one :ro16
  has_one :ro8
  has_one :ro4
  has_one :ro2

MAP_POOL
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :maps

MAP
  :name
  belongs_to :map_pool
  has_many :games

PLAYER
  :name
  belongs_to :race
  belongs_to :team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tournaments
  has_many :games

RACE
  :type {"Protoss", "Terran", "Zerg"}
  has_many :players

TEAM
  :name
  has_many :players

RO32
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :groups, :as => :round,
                    :limit => 8

RO16
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :groups, :as => :round,
                    :limit => 4

RO8
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :matches, :as => :matchup,
                      :limit => 4

RO4
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :matches, :as => :matchup,
                      :limit => 2

RO2
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :matches, :as => :matchup,
                      :limit => 1

GROUP
  :name
  belongs_to :round, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :matchups, :as => :matchup

MATCH
  :type {"bo3", "bo5", "bo7"}
  has_many :games
  belongs_to :matchup, :polymorphic => true

GAME
  belongs_to :match
  has_one :map
  has_one :player
```

Am I missing anything or using anything incorrectly?

**EDIT: The reason why I have separate models for each individual round is because of the way Rounds 32/16 are different from Rounds 8/4/2. Here is a set of sample data that may explain the issues I'm having:**

```
Round of 32:
    Group A:
        Match 1: P1 vs P2
            Game 1
            Game 2
            Game 3
        Match 2: P3 vs P4
            Game 1
            Game 2
            Game 3
        Winners Match: P1 (winner match 1) vs P4 (winner match 2)
            Game 1
            Game 2
            Game 3
        Losers Match: P2 (loser match 1) vs P3 (loser match 2)
            Game 1
            Game 2
            Game 3
        Tiebreak Match: P4 (loser of winners match) vs P2 (winner of losers match)
            Game 1
            Game 2
            Game 3
    [etc. Group B through Group H]
Round of 16:
    [similar to Round of 32 but only groups A through D]
Round of 8:
    Match 1: P1 vs P2
        Game 1
        Game 2
        Game 3
        Game 4
        Game 5
    Match 2: P3 vs P4
        Game 1
        Game 2
        Game 3
        Game 4
        Game 5
    Match 3: P5 vs P6
        Game 1
        Game 2
        Game 3
        Game 4
        Game 5
    Match 4: P7 vs P8
        Game 1
        Game 2
        Game 3
        Game 4
        Game 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still say your rounds should be a single model. It seems that the differences between they types are logical not structural. So I'd do a Round table and add the type attribute (take advantage of single table inheritance ?).

As a fellow SC fan I'd be happy to help model it out if you like.

Also: player >-- race ? Are you sure? I can't change races between games or even tournaments?!

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip about the Round model.

Also, for the Player/Race issue, you bring up a good point. I just thought it would make searches a bit easier (i.e. rather than having to search through all players with type "RACE", having table per race may take a little more work when changing a player's race, but it would make lookups a bit faster)

Comment: erm, i dont think you understood my race suggestion there. I structure it like this.
`player >- participates -< rounds` and the participation table would hold the data on race. (this will also allow for 1+ v 1+ games in the future).